# Get ACF field from WordPress menu or sub-menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a menu where I need to loop through all the child items of a parent menu item in Wordpress to get an ACF field that's part of the child item.

```
Menu parent 1 <-- ID is 95
  child of menu parent 1 <-- Get ACF field from this child
  child of menu parent 1 <-- Get ACF field from this child
```

How do I get the ACF fields of child menu items?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through menus and check if the field exists like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'mlnc_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function mlnc_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
  // loop
  foreach( $items as $item ) {
    // vars
    $your_field = get_field('menu_placeholder', $item);
    // append field
    if( $your_field ) {
      $item->title .= ' <span>'.$your_field.'</span>';
    }
  }
  // return
  return $items;
}
```

check for more details here, [the ACF reference for menus](http://advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/)